# notification icon image won't change (android)

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

this is my code :

```
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_test_1);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_test_1)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Sssssssssssssssssssss")
                        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```

but it wont change the image, it just stay as the launcher icon, is there any problem?

Comment: what for you create bitmap from large icon?

Comment: did you mean why i'm using bitmap? because large icon requires to use bitmap

Answer (score 0):

1-Create your photo in the size of 128 * 128.

2-Replace the code with the following code:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.Your photo with a size of 128 x 128);
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_test_1)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Sssssssssssssssssssss")
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
```